# How do I add sum of all amounts after group by in Access SQL?

Tags: ms-access

I have my query written as:

```
SELECT Category.Category, Sum(Hub.Amount) AS TotalAmount
FROM Hub, From_Who, Category
WHERE (((Hub.FromWhoID)=From_Who.FromWhoID) And ((From_Who.CategoryID)=Category.CategoryID))
GROUP BY Category.Category;
```

It outputs all the existing categories with their corresponding amounts. I want to put in a code that adds one more category to the list: "Total" (which corresponds to the sum of all amounts).

What would this code look like?

Comment: you cant, at least in microsoft access

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `UNION` query to achieve this - try the following:

```
SELECT 
    Category.Category, Sum(Hub.Amount) AS TotalAmount
FROM 
    (Hub INNER JOIN From_Who ON Hub.FromWhoID = From_Who.FromWhoID) 
    INNER JOIN
    Category ON From_Who.CategoryID = Category.CategoryID
GROUP BY 
    Category.Category
UNION
SELECT 
    "Total" AS Category, Sum(Hub.Amount) AS TotalAmount 
FROM Hub
```